# How can I silently install Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, installation, silent-install

I want to make a silent installation of Google Chrome Beta. I've tried invoking the `ChromeSetup.exe` downloader with `/s` or `/-ms` but nothing worked.

Then I've downloaded the standalone installation version, and tried the same, but got the same result – the silent installation doesn't work.

Basically what I need is to avoid the post-installation dialog ("Choose a search engine"). Is there a way to silently choose Google?

Comment: Have a look at this http://www.techygeekshome.co.uk/2014/06/google-chrome-msi-download-silent.html which may help.

Answer (score 25):

1. Download [the Chrome installer](http://dl.google.com/chrome/install/375.126/chrome_installer.exe).
2. Use the switches `/silent` and  `/install` like so:

   ```
   chrome_installer.exe /silent /install
   ```
3. Enjoy!

Comment: Downloading the MSI in an unattended install process is a frigging pain, since it has a GUID attached to it's path to the MSI. This one is at least clean, and without a random generated GUID which timesout after a while and the download becomes unavailable. Thanks!

Comment: Tried this just now with the provided link but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Works for me when installing Chrome 59.0.3071.86 using the standalone installer

Answer (score 12):

Installing with the [MSI file](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/business/browser/) with the [q](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367988%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) flag will give you a silent install.

Comment: This wont' work on an older Windows XP machine without the SP to support msi installs. (And yes, I run into people with older machines all the time).

Comment: I'd understood Windows Installer 2 (which supports the q flag) to be included in RTM of XP, though I could be wrong.

On the other hand - Chrome itself only supports [XP SP 2 and later](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95411) which seems to make it a little academic.

Answer (score 8):

It is possible to silent install Chrome using [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/).

**Install Chocolatey**

Open a commandprompt as an Administrator and issue:

```
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin
```

**Install Chrome**

```
choco install googlechrome
```

Answer (score 6):

For a setup file which has .msi extension:

```
msiexec /q /i GoogleChromeStandoloneEnterprise.msi
```

For detailed information, [see this blog post](http://www.cethint.com/?p=103).

Answer (score 2):

If only PowerShell 2.0 had a native one-line curl...
For simplicity, I created my own, which takes a url and downloads the content.  If you need basic auth, I've provided parameters for that too.

To get up and running:

1. Load a PowerShell console
2. Create a ps1, psm1 or simply copy and paste and execute this code block in PowerShell.
3. The code will call `Get-Url` and silently execute `chrome_installer.exe`

NOTE: if you have any issues:

- ensure you are running PowerShell in Administrator mode
- C:\temp is an existing directory that you can access (or just change your `$filePath`)

```
# our curl command, with basic authentication if $credentials provided
function Get-Url {
    param(
        [string]$url, # e.g. "http://dl.google.com/chrome/install/375.126/chrome_installer.exe"
        [string]$filepath, # e.g. "c:\temp\chrome_installer.exe"
        [string]$credentials # e.g. "username:pass"
    )

    $client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient;

    if ($credentials) {
        $credentialsB64 = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($credentials) ;
        $credentialsB64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($credentialsB64) ;    
        $client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + $credentialsB64) ;
    }    

    $client.DownloadFile($url, $filepath);
}

# curl and run silent install
Get-Url http://dl.google.com/chrome/install/375.126/chrome_installer.exe c:\temp\chrome_installer.exe ;
c:\temp\chrome_installer.exe /silent /install ;
```

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly - tested on Windows 10 EDU 64 bit using PDQ Deploy on 10 laptops at once: Also works with the offline installer chromestandalonesetup.exe with tags /silent /install on PDQ Deploy

```
msiexec.exe /i "\\tabeguache\c$\PDQ Deploy Packages\googlechromestandaloneenterprise64.msi"  /quiet /passive
```

I highly recommend installing the free `PDQDeploy`. Just download the MSI and enter the custom install command as above and choose the computers you want to install it on. It installs onto as many computers you want, 8 at a time queued, without having to touch the computer, whether anyone is logged on to the machine or not. If you also install `PDQInventory` you can install it onto all Domain workstations in surprisingly few clicks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you want, but:

`choco install chrome`

Answer (score 1):

You can "silently install" Google Chrome on any modern Windows OS with the following Powershell one-liner:

```
$LocalTempDir = $env:TEMP; $ChromeInstaller = "ChromeInstaller.exe"; (new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://dl.google.com/chrome/install/375.126/chrome_installer.exe', "$LocalTempDir\$ChromeInstaller"); & "$LocalTempDir\$ChromeInstaller" /silent /install; $Process2Monitor =  "ChromeInstaller"; Do { $ProcessesFound = Get-Process | ?{$Process2Monitor -contains $_.Name} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name; If ($ProcessesFound) { "Still running: $($ProcessesFound -join ', ')" | Write-Host; Start-Sleep -Seconds 2 } else { rm "$LocalTempDir\$ChromeInstaller" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Verbose } } Until (!$ProcessesFound)
```

Well, technically it isn't an one-liner, but it works like it is. It will work even if IE Enhanced Security is turned on, thus making it very useful for Windows Server brand-new installations when IE will prevent you from downloading Chrome.

You can also [read here](http://www.ryadel.com/en/install-google-chrome-with-powershell-script/) for additional info.

Comment: Not a fan of the one liner, but I love this because it did exactly what I needed - installs chrome and waits for it to be fully installed before continuing. If only there was a simple /wait on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to install Google Chrome v42 via MSI was failing for me using the silent install commands in this post. When I ran the MSI manually, i found that it pops up a UAC prompt, and that the silent install was failing due to the UAC prompt being blocked.

This is a really good [article](http://csi-windows.com/blog/all/27-csi-news-general/335-how-to-silence-the-uac-prompt-for-per-machine-msi-packages-for-non-admins) explaining the relationship between MSI and UAC.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this command :

`start /wait msiexec /i "%~dp0%googlechromestandaloneenterprise.msi%" /qn /l*`

First download msi file.

For more information read [this article](http://www.get-itsolutions.com/silent-install-google-chrome-and-disable-auto-update/)